# IDE indicates that my if else statement is redundant and I need an explanation to why

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I am a beginner in programming. The Netbeans IDE is indicating that the following if-else statement is redundant:

```
public boolean x = false;

private void add_labelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

    jPanel2.setVisible(x);
        if(x==false){
            x=true;
        }else
            x=false;
}
```

And if I correct this if-else statement using the IDE it turns the code into this:

```
public boolean x = false;

private void add_labelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

    jPanel2.setVisible(x);
       x = x == false;
}
```

I need a simple explanation on the second code and how come it has a similar function to the first code.

EDIT: I  really understand it now thanks to everyone who explained it in detail, I learned something new today thanks for all the replies everyone.
(I felt stupid afterwards lol)

Comment: Well it would be better just to use `x = !x;` to be honest... but look at the second piece of code - it's evaluating `x == false`, and using that as the new value for `x`.

Comment: I am still confused at second code though, I was using an if-else statement how did it turn out like that because I don't see anything that set the boolean to true.

Comment: What's the result of `x == false` if `x` is currently true? What's the result if `x` is currently false?

Comment: Thanks bro, somehow that last comment made me understand the logic.

Comment: Please mark an answer correct from below, if they helped you. Or you can upvote too. Giving back to peple who helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = x == false;
```

explanation

if x is False, `x == false` is true and thus, x becomes true

if x is true, `x == false` becomes false and thus, x becomes false

`x == false` is a conditional operator, due to the presence of `==`, just like if-condition and returns a value of true or false

`==` is equality checking conditional operator and is returning a value of true or false, as explained in answer. This returned value gets assigned to x.

You could also use `x = !x` to write even simple code

Comment: Yes, it is a conditional operator. `==` is equality checking conditional operator and is returning a value of true or false, as explained in answer. This returned value gets assigned to x. And this, both the codes are doing same stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just read through the second one.

This part is nice and simple - setting x

```
x =
```

The next part of what is being set

```
x == false
```

it is evaluating what x and checking if its false, if its false set x to true otherwise set x to false.

Since you are basically negating x, you could use

```
x = !x
```

This will just flip x between true and false

Comment: I am still confused :(

Comment: lets put values into x and see what we get out. If x = false 
(false == false) = true and (true == false) = false, these are the values you are setting in your if statement

Comment: Actually after reading through all the replies this made sense now thanks!